# MYSQL compare dates in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date, datetime

I have 2 tables:

1. users : 
   I am doing a first query to select a `datetime` variable stored in table `users` called `last_check`. I am using this variable in a second query to select  from table
2. notif : `notif` just the entrys that have in the `date` column a value larger than the `last_check` variable. The `date` column is a datetime mysql column.

   -> this returns no result

   `"SELECT * FROM notif WHERE userid = '"+ req.session.idd +"' AND date > '"+row[0].last_check+"'"`

   `console.log(row[0].last_check)  returns Tue Feb 02 2016 18:24:19 GMT-0500 (EST)`

How do I compare those dates? Is it possible to this in just one query?

Comment: Why are you doing it in javascript, and not with 1 select that joins the 2 tables and brings the relevant rows from notif?

Comment: Sound like a good idea? How the query would look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the user table to your query:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM notif n, users u
WHERE n.userid = '"+ req.session.idd +"' AND
  n.date > u.last_check AND
  u.userid=n.userid
```